# foo || (foo = this.foo) what does it do?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I want to know what this line does:

```
foo || (foo = this.foo)
```

in the following function definition

```
someFunction: function(foo)  
{   
    foo || (foo = this.foo);  
    ...  
}
```

Comment: I wonder if this kind of defaulting operation will ever catch on, I thought I was the only one writing that kind of self-obfuscated code.

Comment: It's like reading the output of the closure compiler.

Answer (score 6):

This is probably more commonly written as:

```
someFunction: function(foo)  
{   
    foo = foo || this.foo;
    // do something with foo
}
```

All it does is set the `foo` parameter to the context's `foo` instance variable if either:

- `someFunction` is called without parameters
- `someFunction` is called with a `falsy` parameter such as false, empty string, 0, null, or undefined.

As an example, let's say that someFunction is defined inside an object literal like so:

```
var myObject = {
    foo: "default value of foo",
    someFunction: function(foo)  
    {   
        foo = foo || this.foo;
        // do something with foo
    }
}
```

This way, `someFunction`'s parameter `foo` falls back to a default value if needed.

Comment: +1 because this is the only accurate and non-misleading answer apart from `1. 2.` implying that both must hold, which is nonsensical, but still ;) I'd add an "either" after the `if: `

Answer (score 4):

If `foo` isn't handed to `someFunction`, or if the value of `foo` evaluates to false, `foo` takes `this.foo` as a 'default' value

edit: It works because many programming languages, including JS, use [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). If `foo` evaluates to true, the engine won't bother evaluating the `(foo = this.foo)` part, since the whole statement is already true.

If `foo` is false (and remember JS isn't strongly typed, so in this usage that sort of means "isn't supplied"), then the second part *is* evaluated, and it ends up setting the value of `foo`.

Comment: `If foo isn't handed to someFunction, it takes this.foo as a 'default' value` is is horribly misleading! The last sentence rectifies this to some extent, but still.

Comment: From a language perspective, yes, it's not a great explanation. It describes the purpose of the code however - 'allows for default arguments', which its what (I believe) OP wanted. I then tired to address the caveats at a level commensurate to the question. Happy to make any edits you might suggest, of course.

Comment: It's just that the argument will be considered omitted even if has been provided in the form of an empty atring or zero for example. So someFunction(0) will not pass zero. I'd just clarify on that sooner, rather than implying it in the last sentence.

Comment: It's difficult to strike a balance between answering as concisely as possible, and covering important gotchas, caveats, etc. I try to practice describing things in as few words as possible. As the quote goes, “I didn't have time to write a short letter, so I wrote a long one instead.”. Anyhow, thanks for the feedback. Edit made.

Comment: That's when I'm glad I don't have to write it. You gave a good point, and my own explanations often get a bit wordy ;)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it checks if `foo` the parameter, is set, and if not, overwrites it with a default (`this.foo`).

Answer (score 0):

Generally, `foo` is a placeholder for a dummy variable.

```
someFunction: function(foo)
{
    // If foo is null, then foo is assigned with this.foo
    // If not, the original value of foo is taken.
    foo || (foo = this.foo);
}
```

Comment: @phant0m I removed. Is it fine now? I don't get what you said `secondly`.

Comment: It's not about the word, I just wanted to point out that it's not important that `foo is a dummy variable` ;) With `secondly`, I meant `This statement checks if the foo is null or not.` which is not correct.

Comment: @phant0m I have removed that statement too.

Comment: `If foo is null, then foo is assigned with this.foo` is wrong as well.

Comment: @phant0m You can say what I should write instead. Just for removing this downvote. Let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at Abdullah Jibaly's answer. The thing is, that `foo || x` will evaluate to `x` whenever `foo` is ["falsy"](http://11heavens.com/falsy-and-truthy-in-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

```
foo || (foo = this.foo);
```

is the same as

```
if (!!!foo) {
    foo = this.foo;
}
```

Comment: LOL. You really, really, really want to make sure that variable is not not not false, eh?

Comment: Ok, my bad, i despise myself and repent in dust and ashes.

Comment: having a tripple ! makes any sense?

Comment: @Akinsa: "yes" it's like doing (x == true) == true. And "no" because it's the same as a single !